# jQuery Image Selector With Variables As Attributes

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I'm having issues with jQuery selectors (again). I'm sure this is really simple but I seem to be strugling.

This is the selector that's causing me problems. The variables ClassImg and TitleImg all seem to be ok.

```
$('img [class=' + ClassImg + '][attr="1"][title=' + TitleImg + ']').attr("src", "../graphics/stars/FullStar.png");
```

I've been fiddling about with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/aYr8e/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Dan

Comment: Could you please add the simplest possible html tree to the question? The jsFiddle example has more code than what is needed at a first glance, but without the html you are trying to match it's impossible to say what is wrong with your selector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some helpful notes:

1. You can use `img.' + ClassImg` the class selector instead of the [attr] selector for class names.
2. I assume you mean `alt=1`
3. Since you are using jquery look at using [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) as it will help produce less [Unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).
4. If you use Unobtrusive javascript wrap your event handlers in `$(document).ready(function(){});` or simply `$(function(){});`

From looking at what your example it appears like you want to highlight the stars on hover.
Since you have the stars under a `<p>` tag you can call parent on the `<img>` and than use the [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to select the `<img/>` stars less than the current star you are hovering over.  Putting this all together ends up with something like the following:

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    var AltImg = $(this).attr("alt");
    $(this).parent().children(":lt(" + AltImg + ")").attr("src", "http://www.sweetashoney.co.uk/graphics/stars/FullStar.png");
},
function() {
    $('img[name=FeedbackStar]').attr("src", "http://www.sweetashoney.co.uk/graphics/stars/EmptyStar.png");
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/aYr8e/12/).

Hope this helps!  If I missed the mark let me know and I will revisit.

Comment: wow! That's perfect, I knew there must have been a easier way, ...but at 2am I wasn't functioning too well,lol. Thanks Mark!